# Why does Transparent color not work on Panel

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, .net-2.0

I don't know what is wrong here. Firstly It is Winforms application using .net 2.0.

I have a Panel (backcolor set to Transparent, I want it to be see-through).

At run-time I want to overlap this panel on controls, show a new panel over it (as to make it feel like a model dialog). but the panel is not rendered transparent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you render a panel as transparent in WinForms, it is not true alpha transparency. I believe that at the point of setting it to transparent, it uses the colour located underneath / in the parent container as it's background colour, so it is more like simulated transparency.

More info @ http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943454 along with a solution for this, but seems quite longwinded for a somewhat simple task.

Comment: The Microsoft link is broken, could it have been https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/controls-with-built-in-owner-drawing-support ?